# Virtualbox上のKaliLinuxでWi-Fiアダプタが認識されない

Tags: virtualbox

研究でairmon-ng等を使った無線Wi-Fiクラッキングをしたいのですが、
Virtualbox上のKali LinuxでWi-Fiアダプタを認識しようとしても割り当てに失敗したと表示され、難航しています。(iwconfigで表示されない。)

環境
ホストOS:Windows10
ゲストOS:Kali Linux
Wi-Fiアダプタ:RealTeck 8812AU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB NIC(ALFA製)

試したこと
・Virtualboxの設定のUSB欄でUSB1.1,USB2.0,USB3.0全て試行
・Wi-Fiアダプタをバッファローのアダプタに変えて試してみたが結果は変わらず

[image: VirtualboxのUSB欄の設定]
[image: エラー内容]

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 3年前の記事ですが、もしかしたら参考になるかも。[【VirtualBox】無線ランアダプタが認識されない](https://teratail.com/questions/56785)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
単純にWi-FiアダプタのドライバをゲストOSにインストールすればいいだけでした。